# Why does the updating of the default route entry of physical interface take 1 minute in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, network, vpn

I created a logical interface using my VPN Application and added the default route - in the routing table as my logical interface.
To add the default route programmatically, I have to delete the existing default and then add the new one.

Once added, the system is updating the routing table with the default entry of the physical interface in the following two scenarios:

- When the machine is rebooted or the VPN application is launched for the first time, the system takes exactly 65 seconds to update the routing table with the default route entry of the physical interface.
- In other normal cases the system is immediately updating the routing table with the default route entry of the physical interface once the application has added the route entry for the logical interface.

Due to the 65 second delay, the system is losing internet connectivity for 65 seconds.

I tried flushing the arp tables and routing tables also but the delay still persists.

Is there any solution to overcome this delay?
Or is it the default behaviour of Mac OS X?

Comment: Please add the VPN app you use.

Comment: Its a custom VPN application that I am developing